# Wordpress theme doesn't have alt tags in their shortcodes except for one image style. I am trying to override that, but it keeps breaking

Tags: php, wordpress

I made the mistake of purchasing a theme that for some reason does not have an easy way to use alt tags. When I add the images in to wordpress, it gives me the option to put in the alt tag, which I always have done, but it never actually shows up on the page.

I am trying to figure out how to do it, but it appears that the themes shortcode only allows the alt attribute for one type of image, but there are 3 types of images in the theme. The first block of code that you will see below is from the photo frame, which is just the regular photo addition into a post. It has the spot for an alt tag.

As soon as I try to add that to the code in the other option, which is a banner list, it breaks all the code and gives me an error saying:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING,
>   expecting ')' in

I would like to add the alt attribute to the second block of code.

**This is the code that works:**

```
    // Photo Frame
add_shortcode('photo', 'theme_shortcode_photo');
function theme_shortcode_photo($atts, $content = null, $code) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'size' => '',
        'width' => null,
        'height' => null,
        'frame' => 'true',
        'title' => false,
        'link' => false,
        'lightbox' => 'image',
        'align' => 'none',
        'icon' => 'zoom',
        'target' => '_self',
        'alt' => ''
    ), $atts));

    if( $width == null )
    switch( $size ) {
        case 'small' : $width = 200;
            break;
        case 'medium' : $width = 400;
            break;
        case 'big' : $width = 675;
            break;
    }

    $original_image_src = $content;
    $resized_image_src = theme_get_image( $original_image_src, $width, $height, true );

    $lightbox = $lightbox ? 'gz-fancy-' . $lightbox : '';
    $align = 'align-' . $align;
    $frame = ( $frame != 'true' ) ? 'photo-glass-frame' : '';
    $title_box = $title ? '<div class="photo-title">'. $title .'</div>' : '';
    $title = $title ? 'title="' . $title . '"' : '';
    $play_mask = ( $icon == 'play' ) ? '<span class="play-mask"></span>' : '';
    $icon = 'icon-' . $icon;

    $img_tag = '<img src="'. $resized_image_src .'" alt="'.$alt.'" />';
    if( $link ) $img_tag = '<a href="'.$link.'" class="'. $lightbox . '" ' . $title .' target="' . $target . '">' . $img_tag . $play_mask . '</a>';

    return <<<RET
[raw]
<div class="photo-frame-wrap $align" style="width:{$width}px;">
<div class="photo-frame $frame $icon">
$img_tag
</div>
$title_box
</div>
[/raw]
RET;
}
```

**This is the code that does not work:**

```
    // Banner List
    add_shortcode('banner_list', 'theme_shortcode_banner_list');
    function theme_shortcode_banner_list($atts, $content = null, $code) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'align' => 'left',
        'grid_height' => 100,
        'grid_width' => 200,
        'fx_bw' => false
        'alt' => ''
    ), $atts));
    $id = mt_rand(0, 9999);


    $class = 'banner-list banner-list-' . $align;
    $list = '';
    if (!preg_match_all("/(.?)\[(img)\b(.*?)(?:(\/))?\](?:(.+?)\[\/img\])?(.?)/s", $content, $matches)) {
        return do_shortcode($content);
    } else {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
            $matches[3][$i] = shortcode_parse_atts($matches[3][$i]);

            $original_image_src = $matches[5][$i];
            $resized_image_src = theme_get_image( $original_image_src, $grid_width, $grid_height );
            $img = '<img src="' . $resized_image_src . '" />';

            $greyscale = ( $fx_bw ) ? 'class="greyscale"' : '';

            if( isset( $matches[3][$i]['link'] ) ) {
                $list .= '<li ' . $greyscale . '><a href="'.$matches[3][$i]['link'].'">'.$img.'</a></li>';
            } else {
                $list .= '<li ' . $greyscale . '>'.$img.'</li>';
            }
        }
    }

    return <<<RET
<ul class="$class">
$list
</ul>
RET;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error. Please add a comma after "'fx_bw' => false" in  the array like below

`'fx_bw' => false,
'alt' => ''`

Comment: You are the best. Thanks!